# Cannot Leave Trello Board

Tags: trello

A stranger just added me to a Trello board, and the options for leaving the board/organization and commenting are turned off. I am worried now about the privacy of other boards tied to this account. Any way to get off this board and also prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Contact FogCreek directly and ask (they are awesome). Since this is a security concern, they'll help you promptly ...

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me by viewing the board at websitesfortrello.com I can't get off the board.  When I chatted with the guy at the websites site, he actually told me i had somehow given him the power to change and even delete my other boards.  I have contacted Trello and am awaiting a response.

Very concerning, even if the guy was just messing with me, I ought to be able to remove his board from my Trello Account

Comment: How does this provide answer to the question?